# Does Couchbase 5 makes ElasticSearch useless for Full Text Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, couchbase

Couchbase FTS is now an official feature in version 5. Why would one still use ElasticSearch along with Couchbase?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/full-text-search-overview.html):

> Couchbase FTS is similar in purpose to other search software such as
>   ElasticSearch or Solr. **Couchbase FTS is not intended as a replacement**
>   for third party search software if search is at the core of your
>   application. It is a simple and lightweight way to add search to your
>   Couchbase data without deploying additional software and servers. If
>   you have many queries which look like `SELECT ... field1 LIKE %pattern% OR field2 LIKE %pattern`, then full-text search may be right for you.

It will depend on your specific use case, but there is a reason why search is a complicated problem and some products spent years and years on working on that (and continue).

Answer (score 1):

Full text search NOT EQUAL Search engine. Full Text Search does support a lot of functions that ElasticSearch provides. For example in ElasticSearch you can set weight of fields in result set, do geo search etc. Couchbase full text search is just full text search implementation, i.e. basic string matching function in specially indexed field only.

So, if your task is to do basic search on sub string as a part of a query, then you don't need ElasticSearch anymore. It make development quicker and infrastructure cheaper. However, if you are building system that need proper search engine, then you need ElasticSearch as much as before.